# Why can't I move a node from X=600 to X=0 (keeping Y the same) so an image goes from right to left?

Tags: javafx-8

```
//...circle1 is at x=0 y=100 (or whatever Y)

TranslateTransition moveCircle1 = new TranslateTransition();
moveCircle1.setDuration(Duration.seconds(5));
moveCircle1.setToX(600);
moveCircle1.setNode(circle1);
moveCircle1.play();
// this works perfect to move the circle from left to right but...see below

//...circle2 is at x=600 y=100 (or whatever Y)

TranslateTransition moveCircle2 = new TranslateTransition();
moveCircle2.setDuration(Duration.seconds(5));
moveCircle2.setToX(0);
moveCircle2.setNode(circle2);
moveCircle2.play();
// this does not work for some reason???

//I tried to reverse the starting and ending center position of node circle 
//but does not work

//...circle2 is at x=600 y=100(or whatever)

TranslateTransition moveCircle2 = new TranslateTransition();
moveCircle2.setDuration(Duration.seconds(5));
moveCircle2.setToX(0);
moveCircle2.setNode(circle2);
moveCircle2.play();
// this does not work for some reason???
```

I want the circle (or image) to move from right side of screen to the 
left side until it disappears then start over. 
It does not move.

Comment: I got it to work. I guess you are not moving it to a new node given x,y position, you are actually telling the position how much to add to it to get to the new position. Say if I start at x=100 and want to move to the origin(x=0) then you put myVariableName.setToX(-100);

Comment: Your transitions only specified the target value which means if at the start of the animation the circle is at `translateX = 0` no animation happens at all. specify `fromX` to change this or make sure you initialize the circle with `translateX = 600`